# Excel: Find duplicates with extra condition

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find duplicates in a row but I'm only interested in duplicates where a condition is met.

```
      A    B       C
1|    1    a       FALSE
2|    2    b       FALSE
3|    3    TEST    TRUE
4|    4    a       FALSE
5|    3    e       TRUE
6|    6    f       FALSE
7|    6    g       FALSE
```

Column C is here an example of what I'd like as an output. So I'm looking for duplicates in column A while checking if one of the duplicates has an adjacent cell with the value "TEST". If a row has a duplicate in column A and one of the duplicates has "TEST" in it's B-column I want column C to return TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Excel 2007 or later:

=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,A1,$B$1:$B$7,"TEST")>0

Copy down as required.

Regards

Comment: Thank you @xor-lx but this is what I have been able to produce myself. However, I'm looking to get a TRUE on both of the duplicate's rows. Your COUNTIFS gives FALSE on row 5 which I'm looking to be TRUE.

Comment: I disagree! It returns TRUE for both 3|TEST (row 3) and 3|e (row 5). Perhaps you didn't place this formula in row 1, which I assumed was the starting point for your data, or you didn't amend the references accordingly if my assumption was incorrect?

Comment: I simply forgot the $. It works like a charm and your assumptions were correct. Sorry for the confusion and thank you!